# RE: Remove ask question in answer colums

Tags: support

I have recommended removing some question asked in a column of the answer. I have checked my history still it in the answer column.  moderator, please check and remove the question.

https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/145833

https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/145887

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rama Chandran M, Thanks for this question.

The posts are removed Now

Comment: Thanks for removed :)